# Functions that fail to have radial limits almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, boundary-value-problem

It is from Stein and Shakarchi's *Real Analysis*, Problem 4, Chapter 4.

> This problem provides some examples of functions that fail to have radial limits almost everywhere.
>
> (a) At almost every point of the boundary unit circle, the function $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n}$ fails to have a radial limit.
>
> (b) More generally, suppose $F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^{2^n}$. Then, if $\sum |a_n|^2 = \infty$ the function $F$ fails to have radial limits at almost every boundary point. However, if $\sum |a_n|^2 < \infty$, then $F \in H^2 (\mathbb{D})$, and we know by the proof of Theorem 3.3 that $F$ does have radial limits almost everywhere.

The statement regarding the case where $\sum |a_n|^2 < \infty$ is fairly easy. How to prove it in the case where $\sum |a_n|^2 = \infty$?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum |a_n|^2 <\infty$ ?

Comment: @Ruy Yes. Let me correct the original question. Thanks!